# How to select information from 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get data from two tables:

```
$con = getDbConnect();
$edit = $_GET['edit'];

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM admininfo where email='" . $edit . "'");
    $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM adminaccount where email='" . $edit . "'");

while ($admininfo = mysqli_fetch_array($result, $results)) {
```

Comment: Start by reading the manual:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php to see how wrong your code is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a single query no matter how many tables you're selecting from, e.g.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table1 a, table2 b where a.id = ? AND b.id = ?
```

Then you fetch what you need from the result, take a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for that.

-- and, of-course, don't use [select *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).